# Anthos Service mesh (istio) and keycloak pod connection error to external postgres

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, keycloak, istio

I have installed Anthos service mesh in my GKE cluster and a keycloak statefulset that connect to an external database in GCP. When the istio sidecar are in the keycloak pod, I get this error in keycloak container:

> keycloak 07:21:54.00 ERROR ==> Unable to connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

In the istio_proxy container I get this error:

> Error   stsserver       http: Server closed

> Error: failed to start xds proxy: failed to build TLS dial option to talk to upstream: failed to find root CA cert for XDS: root CA file for XDS does not exist ./var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
> 2022-02-28T07:23:00.961316Z     error   failed to start xds proxy: failed to build TLS dial option to talk to upstream: failed to find root CA cert for XDS: root CA file for XDS does not exist ./var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

I have other two pods that connects to the database and thoose works fine, but keycloak doesn't

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details about your setup, what's your goal here ? Additionally - are the two pods that work also connect to this database in GCE ?

Comment: I want to use istio in my cluster. The cluster is in GKE and I have installed Anthos Service mesh. The other two pods (kong and konga) are connected to external database and works fine, but keycloak doesn't

Comment: Have you checked the file with you certificate that's mentioned in the error message ? `failed to find root CA cert for XDS: root CA file for XDS does not exist ./var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` ? Does it actually exist ?

Comment: In the keycloak pod, the file doesn't exist but in the others pods (kong and konga), it does but I didn't configure it, I wonder if was istio who mounts the secret and file ca.crt but I don't know why in keycloak not

Comment: Keycloak is a statefulset, not a normal deployment. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That may be a good way to go - try a normal deployment and let me know.